# ASP.NET Web API handled exception return wrong status code

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have project using ASP.NET Web API 2.0 and have a method in this API throwing an exception:

```
    public void TestMethod()
    {
        throw new Exception("Error40001");
    }
```

When this exception is thrown I have made a handler to handle these sort of things:

```
public class APIExceptionHandler : ExceptionHandler
{
    public override void Handle(ExceptionHandlerContext context)
    {
        var rm = Language.Error.ResourceManager;
        string message = rm.GetString(context.Exception.Message);
        string detailed = "";
        try
        {
            detailed = rm.GetString(context.Exception.Message + "Detailed");
        }
        catch
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(detailed))
            {
                detailed = message;
            }
        }
        HttpStatusCode code = (HttpStatusCode)Enum.Parse(typeof(HttpStatusCode), context.Exception.Message.Replace("Error", "").Substring(0, 3));

        context.Result = new ResponseMessageResult(context.Request.CreateResponse(code,
            new ErrorInformation() { Message = message, DetailedMessage = detailed }));
    }
}

public class ErrorInformation
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string DetailedMessage { get; set; }
}
```

The problem I have is that when I receive this error back it is no longer the same status code that I set it to. The handler picks it up and creates a response message result with error code 400.

[Here you see the result that is returned with status code 400](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PG5hc.jpg)

[image: 400 stts]

But when I receive the error in the browser the status code has changed

[Here you see the status code that is returned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lf4jO.jpg)

[image: cd chged]

[And the content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNDXf.jpg)

[image: cntent]

As can be seen in the last picture the content from the handled exception is at the start, but a default error message has been included and the status code has been overwritten.

The problem I am having is even if i remove the custom error messages from the webconfig the message is the same. Is this some default behavior that can be overridden? Am I missing something important?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting `context.Result` use following code

```
throw new HttpResponseException(context.Request.CreateResponse(code,
            new ErrorInformation() { Message = message, DetailedMessage = detailed }));
```

Comment: This didn't work in the handler but if i replaced the throw exception in the testmethod with throw httpresponseexception it seemed to bypass the handler entirely and then worked. Any idea why this works and the handler doesn't?